# How can I maintainably determine sizeof(struct ...)s?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, maintainability

Say I have a structure:

```
struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    short b;
    char c;
};
```

In Windows, [MSDN states that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx) `int` takes 4 bytes, `short` takes 2 bytes and `char` takes 1 byte. This totals up to 7 bytes.

I understand that most compilers will pad structures with an unspecified number of bytes to improve alignment. So, when I execute this program,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(struct myStruct));
    return 0;
}
```

I get an output of `8`. This means 1 byte was padded.

Is there any way I can maintainably determine `struct` sizes in code (short of adding up individual `sizeof`s)?

I ask this because later, if I need to change my structure to include about fifteen elements more and if I add five more structures, all my `struct` `sizeof`s will change causing things to get messy.

Comment: Why do you need the "logical" size of the struct instead of the real one ?

Comment: Because I'm dealing with sockets and stuff where I'm calculating bytes to send based on structure sizes. So here, actual memory usage doesn't really matter (unless I run out of memory).

Comment: But in that case you need the **real** struct size. Have you thought of struct packing ?

Comment: Not really because I'm not always sending the entire structure. I understand that using the real struct size is much easier, but unfortunately I'm dealing with a massive code-base (which I cannot change even if I wanted to). And yes, I have read about struct packing, but I didn't want to try that out because I've read that it can severely hamper performance.

Comment: I believe that the number of padding bytes as well as their values is _unspecified_ behavior, rather than implementation-defined. As in, the compiler may do as it pleases and it does not need to document how.

Comment: @Lundin, Yes. You are correct. I just saw that clause in the C11 standard.

Comment: @AnishRam You are saying you are not sending the complete struct over the socket, but only parts. Does that mean there is some sort of function that selects certain members of the struct for submission? If so, couldn't you apply `sizeof` in that function, on each of the selected members individually, and calculate the size by adding up the results?

Comment: @AnishRam: Why should sizeof the struct determine number of bytes sent?  You want your wire protocol to be independent of the padding and endianness of the compile host.  So unpack the structure to a byte buffer in a portable way, and send that.

Comment: Are you sure you want to send binary C variables as represented in the sender's memory via the network? If your set of involved platforms isn't strongly restricted this could really cause trouble (endianess, integer sizes, padding ...).

Comment: @jogojapan, I actually cannot modify the send functions even if I wanted to. I am supposed to just add a separate function to send extra data. For code uniformity, I am sticking to the (incorrect) method used in the rest of the code.

Comment: @fizzer, Actually, my application is quite specific, so since we determined endianness to be the same on the target, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @alk, See above comment.

Comment: Can you use two structures - one standard and one packed? The latter will tell you the total size of the actual data in the former and hence the size of any required buffer. You don't need to actually instantiate the packed version. You could use the preprocessor to ensure you have a common definition for both.

Comment: @AnishRam: I'm confused. Your protocol works already, and you aren't allowed to change it, so the endianness and structure packing are guaranteed to be the same at both ends.  Why are you now concerned that struct sizes may differ?  This contradicts your assumptions.

Comment: @fizzer, What I meant is, if I add elements later to the structure, all `sizeof`s may change (due to extra padding). In this case, the original send algorithms might develop bugs. There is a lot of code that relies on buffer length being EXACTLY the same as the data to be sent. All that code is just waiting to break. I did not want my code to be part of the code that breaks. This is why I wanted to accurately calculate `sizeof` existing structures accurately. I hope I made it clearer. If I had mentioned all this in the question, it would have become very localized.

Comment: You don't want your incremental additions to be the ones that break the layout assumptions.  It's conceivable, I suppose.  In that case, you may also want to make static assertions about the offsets of your new elements (see offsetof() macro in stddef.h).

Comment: @fizzer, That function seems useful. I think Alexey's answer is a very good static assertion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce it:

```
#define C_ASSERT(expr) extern char CAssertExtern[(expr)?1:-1]

C_ASSERT(sizeof(struct myStruct) == 7); // or 8, whichever you want
```

Whenever the size diverges from 7, the code will simply cease to compile.

You can do similar things to enforce offsets of structure members. You'll need the `offsetof()` macro for that.

Comment: How would this cease to compile? That macro can be checked only at run-time right? Am I missing something?

Comment: @AnishRam Try it. Declarations are parsed at compile time. `extern char CAssertExtern[(expr)?1:-1]` is a declaration. If it gets a negative element count, the compiler will stop with the appropriate error.

Comment: As a side note, a better way to do compile time asserts is C standard `static_assert`, though only brand new C11 compilers support it. Do make your code compatible with future compilers, name the macro `static_assert` instead of C_ASSERT.

Comment: Oh man! You're right. It works. This is quite nifty. By my understanding, if that condition fails, the compiler will be trying to declare an array of size -1. Correct?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, Just curious, why did you include the `extern` keyword?

Comment: Would you prefer to define `char CAssertExtern[1]` and actually allocate space for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try pragma pack. It helps maintaining an alignment and has many flexibility. check this
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.aix.doc/compiler_ref/pragma_pack.html

Update: just now saw your comment, perhaps pack is not your solution then